# Signature capture image not saving on saveEvent call in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, digital-signature, signature

I am new to react native. I am trying to save signature Image but the function is not even calling. I think its Icon on press issue but when I do console.log on onPress then Its working fine. I think something wrong in function. please help. thanks
here is code.

```
import SignatureCapture from 'react-native-signature-capture';

this.ref = React.createRef();
this.sign = React.createRef();

saveSign = () => {
  this.refs['sign'].saveImage();
};

_onSaveEvent = (result) => {
  this.checkAndroidPermission(result);
};

checkAndroidPermission = async (result) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    save(result);
  } else {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        // Once user grant the permission start downloading

        this.save(result);
      } else {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          ToastAndroid.show('Storage Permission denied.', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        } else {
          AlertIOS.alert('Storage Permission denied.');
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // To handle permission related exception
      console.warn('tryerr', err);
    }
  }
};

save = async (result) => {
  const paths = `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir}/${new Date().getTime()}.png`; // where u need to put that
  try {
    RNFetchBlob.fs
      .writeFile(paths, result.encoded, 'base64') //data.base64 is your photo with convert base64
      .then((value) => {
        RNFetchBlob.fs
          .scanFile([{ path: paths }]) //after save to notify gallry for that
          .then(() => {
            const file = {
              uri:
                Platform.OS == 'android'
                  ? 'file://' + paths //path to your file
                  : paths,
              name: 'sign.png', // which go on server on your file name
              type: 'image/png', // e.g. 'image/jpg'
            };

            this.setState({ base64: file });
            console.log('scan file success');
            console.log('this is fuckiiing file' + JSON.stringify(this.state.base64));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('scan file error');
          });
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e.message));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('fileerror', error.message);
  }
};
```

please ignore this.
I am new to react native. I am trying to save signature Image but the function is not even calling. I think its Icon on press issue but when I do console.log on onPress then Its working fine. I think something wrong in function. please help. thanks I am new to react native. I am trying to save signature Image but the function is not even calling. I think its Icon on press issue but when I do console.log on onPress then Its working fine. I think something wrong in function. please help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

So a few things first, this is very little information to work off, without seeing your views. I'd suggest reading up on how refs work, it's helpful to understand it a little better.

When using refs. You need to use the following syntax to access the object it's pointing to `this.refs.current`.

Also you create a `const ref = React.createRef();` but in the `saveSign` function you use `this.refs` maybe a spelling mistake with that variable.

If you are using a Class-based Component using `const ref = React.createRef();` is fine. But for a Functional-based Component you should rather use `const ref = React.useRef();`. Both will work but `createRef` in a Functional-based Component might cause some undesirable things to happen. `useRef` is a hook and will work better.

Now some changes I'd make based on my experience, your current code will probably work because it's based on the example from that package but there are better ways of doing it:

I had a look at the example code for the package you are using, which I'm assuming you are using it.
I'd recommend trying to replace the `ref` inside the `<SignatureCapture />` component with this: `ref={ref}` then inside the `saveSign()` function calling `this.ref.current.saveImage();` rather than `this.refs["sign"].saveImage();`.

For the `<TouchableHighlight>` component inside render, rather write your `onPress` call like this:

`onPress={saveSign}` and rewriting your `saveSign()` function like this:

```
saveSign = () => {
  this.ref.current.saveImage();
}
```

Otherwise, I suggest just debugging why your functions are not being called. It might be an issue with binding some of those functions if you are using a Class-based component.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solution is here. just remove this line

```
saveImageFileInExtStorage={true}
```